# Is it possible to show line numbers more than 65535 when you validate an xml file using lxml?

Tags: xsd, lxml, xml-validation

I try to validate an xml file with around 1 million lines using lxml. This is my code.

```
import codecs
import lxml.etree as ET

xsd_file = codecs.open(r'test.xsd', 'rb', 'utf-8')
xml_file = codecs.open(r'test.xml', 'rb', 'utf-8')

xmlschema_doc = ET.parse(xsd_file)
xmlschema = ET.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)

doc = ET.parse(xml_file)

print (xmlschema.error_log.filter_from_errors())
```

---

But I found the output always says "65535:0" if the line in error exceeds 65535. That is,

```
file:///C:test.xml:65535:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element 'word': Missing child element(s). 
file:///C:test.xml:65535:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element 'word': Missing child element(s).
file:///C:test.xml:65535:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element 'word': Missing child element(s).
```

So I can't identify where the lines above are. Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug in libXML](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325533), [not in LXML itself persay](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/674775), and has been there since 2006. It appears that it can't easily be fixed due to backwards compatibility issues.

Comment: Time to find an alternative solution :)